# How can I show images upon click in a lightbox using the Full HTML text format?

Tags: media, javascript

I'm using the [Lightbox 2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) module on Drupal 7.  I have added an image field to my Basic Page content type.  On one particular page, I have uploaded several images into that field, which I then inserted into the body (text format: Full HTML) using the [Insert](http://drupal.org/project/insert) module.

Since the images are small, I want to allow users to click on them to open them in a lightbox on the same page.  I read through [the lightbox documentation](http://drupal.org/node/144469) but it seems like it hasn't really been updated for Drupal 7.

I tried the following:

```
<a href="/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/page_screenshots/review.png" rel="lightbox" class="image-large" title="review">
<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/page_screenshots/review.png" alt="review" title="review" class="image-medium" /></div>
</a>
```

However, in this case, when I click the image, nothing happens.  When I add some text, however, like this:

```
<a href="/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/page_screenshots/review.png" rel="lightbox" class="image-large" title="review">
click here for the image</a>
```

The lightbox appears when the text is clicked.  However, I want to show the lightbox when an image is clicked, not when text is clicked.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Lightbox is not really the best choice for Drupal 7. Have a look at the very powerfull [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) Module.

Comment: Thanks, that was a snap.  See this tutorial: http://vimeo.com/19386122